# gplotly Error in gsub("\n", br(), a, fixed = TRUE) : input string 1832 is invalid in this locale

Tags: r

I am trying to use `ggplotly` to do the following:

[image]

It then gives me this error:
`geom_smooth()` using formula `y ~ x`.

> Error in gsub("\n", br(), a, fixed = TRUE) :
> input string 1832 is invalid in this locale

Any fixes?  I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Welcome to SO, JCA! Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.